# vba better way to set all values in array to same thing

Tags: vba, excel

This is a matter of personal curiosity.

In VBA, if I have an array of size 2:

```
Dim r(1) as Variant
```

And I want both values in the array to be -1. I can do this:

```
r(0)=-1
r(1)=-1
```

Or I could iterate through both with a loop and set them to -1.

So my question is, is there any way I can set all the values in an array to the same thing without iterating?

Or, is there any way I can do something like:

```
r = array(-1,-1)
```

This might be a really stupid question but I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: -> why would you ever need to set all the values of an array to be the same?

Comment: @Scott because I will be changing some of them, and I want the default to be -1. Again, I'm just curious if there are better ways of doing this, because I can think of much better ways of doing this in other languages (e.g. matlab)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do it. But then you have to take care while declaring the array

Example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Variant '<~~

    r = Array(-1, -1)

    Debug.Print r(0)
    Debug.Print r(1)
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

See the Excel Help File :) The Array Function returns a `Variant` containing an `array`. You cannot assign an array to another array directly. To assign an array to another array you have to use this method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim r(1) As Variant 
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    s = Array(-1, -1)

    For i = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
       r(i) = s(i)
    Next

    Debug.Print r(0)
    Debug.Print r(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! Just out of curiosity, why can't I declare an array r(1) as an Array(-1,-1) ?

Comment: See the Excel Help File :) The Array Function returns a Variant containing an array. You cannot assign an array to another array directly. See updated post.

Comment: +1 Array() is a function and not a declaration statement. It takes any number of items as its parameter and returns an array of type variant containing those elements. As such you can't declare r(1) as Array(-1,-1). You must declare it as a variant (i.e. the datatype returned by the Array function).

Comment: @Alec: I got confused with your last comment `why can't I declare an array r(1) as an Array(-1,-1)`. I think your query has already been answered by sid, that you can't you can't assign an array to another array directly.

Comment: This is what I still don't understand: the two types of arrays will end up being EXACTLY THE SAME. They will both be arrays of type 'variant/variant (0 to 1)', of the same size. In terms of how they look in watch in debug mode, they are 100% exactly the same. Since they are the same data type, why I can't I assign one to the other?

Comment: No they will not be exactly same. A lot of difference. `Dim x as Variant` creates one variable of variant type. While `Dim x(1) as Variant`will create an **array** of Variant type. You can assign the output of Array function to one of the variant array members (since you have 2 variants when u do x(1)) and it should readily accept it. You got the point? Or want me to explain it with an example? :)

Comment: I just posted the explanation in a separate answer. Hope that clears the doubts :)

Comment: I think I get it now. `Dim y as Variant` creates a single variant, whereas `Dim x(1) as Variant` creates an array of variants. Only if I store x(1) as a new single variant (e.g. `Dim z as Variant` `z=x`) is it actually the same data type as my the original variant y. i guess variants are weird like that.

Comment: Yes, you got the point now. And besides being 'wierd' sometimes, I also avoid them (unless absolutely necessary) because they eat a lot of memory space. Each variant variable eats a minimum of 16 bytes of memory, whereas I can usually manage with lesser memory with other variable types (from 1 to 8 bytes depending on variable type).  :)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not very good at drawing images. But this should give you and make clear the concepts associated with variant arrays.

[image: variant versus variant array]

Comment: + 1 for going over and beyond :)